# Better pattern for caching results

Tags: caching, haskell, refactoring

I'm running a number of times now into a similar pattern which is error-prone (typos can skip some caching) and simply doesn't look nice to me. Is there a better way of writing something like this?

```
sum_with_cache' result cache ((p1,p2,p3,p4):partitions) = let
        (cache_p1, sol1) = count_noncrossing' cache p1
        (cache_p2, sol2) = count_noncrossing' cache_p1 p2
        (cache_p3, sol3) = count_noncrossing' cache_p2 p3
        (cache_p4, sol4) = count_noncrossing' cache_p3 p4
    in sum_with_cache' (result+(sol1*sol2*sol3*sol4)) cache_p4 partitions
```

So basically N operations which can update the cache?

I could write also something like:

```
process_with_cache' res cache _ [] = (cache, res)
process_with_cache' res cache f (x:xs) =
    let (new_cache, r) = f cache x
    in process_with_cache' (r:res) new_cache f xs
process_with_cache = process_with_cache' []
```

But that doesn't look really clean either. Is there a nicer way of writing this code?

Comment: If you want to maintain an implicit state between function calls, look at `Control.Monad.State`.

Comment: Are you trying to build a memo table? http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization

Answer (score 8):

Another similar pattern is when you request a series of named random numbers:

```
let (x, rng') = random rng''
    (y, rng)  = random rng'
in (x^2 + y^2, rng)
```

This is exactly when using a state monad is the right way to go:

```
import Control.Monad.State
```

For all random number generators of type `(RandomGen g) => g` there is a state monad `State g`, which threads the state implicitly:

```
do x <- state random
   y <- state random
   return (x^2 + y^2)
```

The `state` function simply takes a function of type `s -> (a, s)` and turns it into a computation of type `State s a`, in this case:

```
state :: (RandomGen g) => (g -> (a, g)) -> State g a
```

You can run a `State` computation by using `runState`, `evalState` or `execState`:

```
runState (liftA2 (\x y -> x^2 + y^2) (state random) (state random))
         (mkStdGen 0)
```